# How can I access the admin windows after install the ithit-webdav-server

Tags: ithit-webdav-server

After I install the ithit-webdav-server on IIS, I'm not sure which account can access. The server is in the domain.

Answer (score 0):

A WebDAV server, based IT Hit WebDAV Server Engine for .NET, is a regular ASP.NET or .NET Core project. It can be deployed to IIS in the same way you will deploy any other ASP.NET or .NET Core project. You can find more in [How to Configure Your WebDAV Server in IIS](https://www.webdavsystem.com/server/server_examples/iis/) article.

You do not need to install the msi package on the server. Msi only required to install [WebDAV Wizards for Visual Studio](https://www.webdavsystem.com/server/documentation/vs_wizards/). It is not required to run you WebDAV server.